# innerHTML from image to video not working

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Right now I have a div with an image on the inside:

```
<div class="video-left" data-lead-id="video-left-id">
  <img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/W5lRXe-9BJSc2cvm4i22woLhyJ70esb7BvmepbFO-u9-0bIIGJe1yKuCovbjt1KZLl9FAESrXx3_8e7Max3vjA=s0" class="role-element leadstyle-image" style="max-width: 340px;">
</div>
```

And I would like to replace it with an embedded YouTube video.  This is my attempt and it is unable to work:

```
<script>
  document.getElementsByClassName("video-left").innerHTML = "<iframe width='340' height='190' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/bbGzYWwr_WI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen=''></iframe>"
</script>
```

With no luck.  Can anyone help me out here?  Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("video-left")[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead for your javascript code

```
document.getElementsByClassName("video-left")[0].innerHTML = "<iframe width='340' height='190' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/bbGzYWwr_WI' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen=''></iframe>"
```

Comment: Yeah, it's important to remember that it's document.getElement**s**ByClassName

Answer (score 0):

[MediaElement YouTube API example](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube)

I think this Link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this I have Edited in your code by setting just id of div and img tags

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        $("#f").remove();
        var x = "<iframe id=" + "\"" + "myframe" + "\"" + " src= " + "\"" + "https://www.youtube.com/embed/bbGzYWwr_WI" + "\"" + " frameborder='0'" + " allowfullscreen=''></iframe>";
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="video-left" data-lead-id="video-left-id"> <img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/W5lRXe-9BJSc2cvm4i22woLhyJ70esb7BvmepbFO-u9-0bIIGJe1yKuCovbjt1KZLl9FAESrXx3_8e7Max3vjA=s0" id="f" class="role-element leadstyle-image" style="max-width: 340px;"></div>
```